# Can I execute commands in real time on Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a particular environment with a strict firewall. Making small incremental changes and then running a job takes forever, it would be much easier if I could enter the container, execute commands and see results in real time.

Is it possible? If not what's the second best thing?

Comment: Run  the docker container locally to your PC/laptop and push only when you need to test a larger update?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have [`Gitlab Runner` installed locally](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/), you can run it against a local repository as long as `.gitlab-ci.yml` is in `pwd`.

For example, `gitlab-runner exec shell tests` runs a job called `tests` using the [`shell` executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html). You can also use the `docker`, `docker-machine`, and `boot2docker` executors.

Note: there are many [limitations](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#limitations-of-gitlab-runner-exec) of running Gitlab Runner locally, including not being able to upload artifacts or use your project's secret variables, so you won't be able to run a fully-defined, production-ready pipeline, but this works great while first defining your pipelines.

For more information, [see the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#gitlab-runner-exec).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to execute interactive commands like you are describing.

As far as the next best thing... if you are using a runner in an auto-scaling config like [Docker+Machine on EC2](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws/), [AWS Fargate](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/), or an executor config with capacity high concurrency like [Kubernetes](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html), then you might be able to run multiple instances of the same job with different configs.

When I am writing a job and can't quite get it right, say for instance that I can't get the syntax right in a Terraform config, I will do the following(using EC2 auto-scaling with Docker-Machine)

- Make a change that I think will fix the failing job
- Commit the changes and start the job
- Assume that what I did will not work. Make alternate changes and commit
- Run the new job while the previous job is still running
- Keep doing this until it works

Doing this isn't the most elegant solution, but when you're stuck debugging a long running job it's better than nothing and you can get several jobs running concurrently. If you watch the job execution in a browser, keeping the jobs organized is important so that you can keep track of how things are reacting to your updated job config and which jobs produce certain results.

For as long as a job is running I leave the browser tab open. Then I can cycle through the browser tabs to see if one of my approaches worked. When one of the jobs succeeds, copy the commit SHA and reset HEAD to point to that commit.

Edit- I want to add that I have also run jobs locally as described by Andrew_Marshall, but I found that the limitations he mentioned keeps it from being a good solution for most jobs.